# Foreach with multiple selectors.

Tags: php

I think the answer to this is probably simple but I'm stumped.  I'm using the following small bit of code to grab info out of some html then write it to a db. ( currently just display it)

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=posttitle front] a, div[class=copy post] a') as $a){
$articles[] = array($a->href,$a->innertext);
}
foreach($articles as $item) {
echo "<p>";
$href =  $item[0];
echo "</p><p>"; 
echo $href;
echo "</p><p>";
echo $item[2];
echo "</p>";
}
```

The code works fine. I get everything I need. But since the information returned by the multiple selectors is for the same link its a pain that for every single link I get an $articles[0[, and $articles[1] for each selector.

Basically those two selectors have information about the same link.

I'm not sure how to ask that clearer, sorry.  Basically what I'd like instead is $articles[0],[1],[2],[3].

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route due to not being able to do this with DOM.  I used the code in the initial example but removed the a attribute from what I was searching for.  I grabbed just the innertext of both div tags.  Wrote that to my db then it was much easier to get out the information with regex.

DOM is great for non messy html.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would like to make records in array unique comparing `href`. You just should use `href` as a key of array:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=posttitle front] a, div[class=copy post] a') as $a){
    $articles[$a->href] = $a->innertext;
}
foreach($articles as $href=>$innertext) {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "</p><p>"; 
    echo $href;
    echo "</p><p>";
    echo $innertext;
    echo "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Actually no.  It pulls an href and an innertext for BOTH selectors. I need the href from the first set and the innertext from the second. Long story short it makes is hard to form the sql query this way.  I think I need to nest a second loop just have not gotten it to work correctly.